# R, 3-way table, how to order

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to order a table that has 3 variables, commonly known as a 3-way table.

I have attached a picture of the structure of the table the replicable code will produce.

[image: 3-waytable]

Is it possible to order this table in a logical way, despite the fact it is essentially split into three sections/groups? For instance, could you order by the column "No" or the column "Yes" based on the values?
For example, when ordering "No" England would be ordered as "Sertosa" (7), Virginica (8), Versicolour (16). Wales would be ordered Versicolor (11), Setoda (12), Virginica... and so on for each section of the table.

#Replicable code using the Iris data built into R:

```
Data <- iris
Data $ var2 <- Data $ Species
Data $ var2 <- sample(Data $ var2)
Data $ var3 <- Data $ Species
Data $ var3 <- sample(Data $ var3)
#making the example clearer
library(plyr)
Data $ var2 <- revalue(Data $ var2, c("setosa"="No", "versicolor"="No","virginica" ="Yes")) 
Data $ var3 <- revalue(Data $ var3, c("setosa"="England", "versicolor"="Wales","virginica" ="Scotland")) 
#3-way Table:
df <- table(Data $ Species, Data $ var2, Data $ var3)
df
```

Kind Regards, James Prentice, a person trying to get to grips with R.

Comment: You cannot since with the table, the rownames take presedence. Thus you will always have the same ordering in all the arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid using `table()` and `array()` in R, as they are hard to work with. Also, I recommend you focus on learning *dplyr*, rather than *plyr*, as *plyr* is no longer maintained.

Instead of using `table()`, work directly with the original data frame:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
Data <- iris
Data$Living <- sample(c("No", "Yes"), size = nrow(Data), replace = TRUE)
Data$Country <- sample(c("England", "Wales", "Scotland"), size = nrow(Data), replace = TRUE)

# Results in one data frame
Data %>%
  group_by(Country, Species) %>%
  summarize(Yes = sum(Living == "Yes"), No = sum(Living == "No")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(Country, Yes) 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Country'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   Country  Species      Yes    No
#>   <chr>    <fct>      <int> <int>
#> 1 England  virginica      2     8
#> 2 England  versicolor     7    15
#> 3 England  setosa        14     5
#> 4 Scotland setosa         5    14
#> 5 Scotland virginica      6    12
#> 6 Scotland versicolor     9     8
#> 7 Wales    setosa         4     8
#> 8 Wales    versicolor     5     6
#> 9 Wales    virginica     14     8

# Results in a list of data frames 
Data %>%
  group_by(Country, Species) %>%
  summarize(Yes = sum(Living == "Yes"), No = sum(Living == "No")) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(Country, Yes) %>%
  split(., .$Country)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Country'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> $England
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Country Species      Yes    No
#>   <chr>   <fct>      <int> <int>
#> 1 England virginica      2     8
#> 2 England versicolor     7    15
#> 3 England setosa        14     5
#> 
#> $Scotland
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Country  Species      Yes    No
#>   <chr>    <fct>      <int> <int>
#> 1 Scotland setosa         5    14
#> 2 Scotland virginica      6    12
#> 3 Scotland versicolor     9     8
#> 
#> $Wales
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Country Species      Yes    No
#>   <chr>   <fct>      <int> <int>
#> 1 Wales   setosa         4     8
#> 2 Wales   versicolor     5     6
#> 3 Wales   virginica     14     8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: "*they are hard to work with*" - [citation needed]. Tables and arrays are very useful and simple for *certain* tasks, just maybe not this particular one. In a tabular/array form, you can do things like `addmargins(tab)` to quickly investigate categorical sums that I can't even imagine how you'd do as simply in a `data.frame`.